# Easiest way to implement paypal shopping for e-books

Tags: python, django, paypal, django-paypal

I have an existing django website, and I would like to sell some pdf files through it using paypal.  The buyer needs to be able to select 1 or more books, get transferred to the paypal site to enter in payment info.  Then after a successful payment, the buyer gets redirected back to my website and the books start downloading automatically.

I have looked at the django-paypal and django-merchent apps, but I don't know how to handle the multiple downloads.  As far as I know, using these apps, after a successful purchase, the app sends a success signal, but doesn't tell me which books were ordered.

What is the best way to implement this either with the django-paypal app or using some other method?  Again, I'm looking for the easiest/quickest solution.

Thanks,

Comment: Don't these app ask you to provide a redirect url ? if they do, create a payment link for these books, send them to the paypal page with redirect url which can consist some id to identify your books and when payment is done send them to `redirect-url`. This redirect url can be a download link to `tar` of these books.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  But I need a shopping cart type functionality, so I would need to get back from paypal a list of books that were purchased.

Comment: Never mind, I think I understand what you're saying.  How can this redirect url be secured so that it only downloads when the signal is received that payment was a success?

Comment: see if these apps take a redirect-url. This is the url where you will be sent by paypal after payment is done. This can be a view where you can do your downloads. I would do this by creating external_ids for each payment link at the time you leave for paypal. When you come back from there paypal will hit the redirect link with this external id by which you will know what books to download. I am not sure about the security concerns you have, can you explain more ?

Comment: So you are proposing that I create a redirect-url such as www.example.com/download=book1&download=book3 correct? Then, when paypal redirects to it I know that book 1 and 3 were purchased. But, what if someone went to that url without paying for them?

Comment: hmm. thats a little tricky. But a basic level of security I can suggest is that you make these id's a string of random ascii. But its not the solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40467/discussion-between-deepankar-bajpeyi-and-bcoop713)

Answer (score 0):

With respect, the question is slightly naive, in that there is typically a separation between the shopping cart, and the payment processing.  A payment returns a binary result - it either worked or it didn't. It is up to your application to recall what was being paid for.

The Paypal API returns the success or failure of an identified payment; plus will happily consume a list of items you give it, so that the user is presented with a breakdown of the total amount.  But note that you are telling paypal what is being paid for. It is consuming that data, not providing it.

So the answer depends entirely upon your chosen solution (django-paypal or django-merchant or whatever).  Read their documentation.  Presumably there is some way to inspect the contents of a recently approved transaction. Cycle through the cart and enable a download of each.

Django-paypal, for example, has no interest of what is in the cart. It just fires a signal when a payment is successful, and passes back the transaction identifier.  Your application  must recall what the transaction was for.

Often it's not as easy as you'd hope.